# SFML - Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable was corrupted, happens every time I run a program

Tags: c++, exception, opengl, sfml

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, I've set up linkers, includes in both debug and release configurations. Each time I try to run a code it throws exceptions at me of corrupted stacks around various variables. Be it 'settings', 'window' etc.

I've ran two codes, both with same results:

```
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{

    sf::ContextSettings settings;

    settings.majorVersion = 3;
    settings.minorVersion = 3;
    settings.depthBits = 24;    
    settings.antialiasingLevel = 16;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Game", sf::Style::Default);

    window.setActive(true);    
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
        window.display();

        sf::Event ev;
        while (window.pollEvent(ev))
        {
            if (ev.type == sf::Event::Closed || sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape))
            {
                    window.close();
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the second:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace sf;
    RenderTexture texture;
    texture.create(800, 600);
    texture.clear(Color::Black);
    texture.display();
    texture.getTexture().copyToImage().saveToFile("D:\output\asd.bmp");

    return 0;
}
```

Both codes throw similar exceptions, the first program throws:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'settings' was corrupted.
>
> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'window' was corrupted.

The second one throws

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'texture' was corrupted.

When I press 'continue' in debugger, it points me to gs_report with unhandled exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00A36859 in Project2.exe: Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun.

Is it something wrong with the codes, or is it something wrong in my setup?

Comment: It seems that the library SFML used was not compiled with the version of your current MSVC (2017). You should recompile this library as stated [here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php)

Comment: After I get my internet connection at normal speeds (probably tomorrow) I'll redownload the libraries and recompile them as in the tutorial.
Then I'll post an update

Comment: Btw: it should be "D:\\output\\asd.bmp" (double backslash)